# How to ask a question with a causative verb

Tags: verbs, questions

What is the correct form of the following sentence?

1. "Did he wash his clothes or **had he had you wash it**?"
2. "Did he wash his clothes or **had he got you to wash it**?"
3. Some other form

It is supposed to mean "did he do wash his clothes himself or did he make you to do it".

Comment: Why not use _did_ again? _Did he wash his own clothes or did he get you to do it?_

Comment: Uh… what?  Cuold you please re-phrase that at least two ways, for clarity?

Comment: It is like did he do wash his clothes himself or did he make you to do it.. was just wandering if it is corr ct...

Comment: Did you know that there is a separate site especially for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)? Based on your question, it seems possible to me that the ELL site would better meet your needs. You can learn some more about the differences between the two sites here: [What is the difference between ELU and ELL?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722)

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your examples are correct.

Here are some correct examples:

> Did he wash his clothes or did he have you wash them?
>   Did he wash his clothes or did he get you to wash them?
>   Did he wash his clothes himself or did he make you do it for him?
>   Had he washed his clothes or had he got you to wash them?